# Get resource class name by request URL/path

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Lets say this is my JAX-RS resource class

```
@Path("/books")
class Book {
    @GET
    @PATH("{id}")
    public Book get() {
    }
}
```

So, when i make a request for "{context}/books/123", its gets to my Book.get() method.

Now, I have a Servlet where I want the resource class name (and method) by the URL? Is there a way to query JAX-RS for the class name that handles a specific resource?

Comment: Maybe, [`ResouceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) will provide the information you need. But it need to be used in a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), when a request is being performed.

Comment: Just to understand better what you are trying to achieve, why do you need to get the class name in a servlet?